# Exchange - routing agent that changes the email massage's recepient from a distribution group type to single email adresses from its members

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, exchange-server-2010

i'm building a routing agent for exchange 2010 using c# (framework 3.5)
i have a 3rd party app that recieves emails , and authenticate users via their email address.

the problem starts when i sent an email to a distribution group,
the "To" field is set to the D-group email address, and it causes my trouble with the 3rd party app.

**how can i convert the TO field of an email massage sent to : xxxGroup@xxx.com**

**into: user1inGroup@xxx.com;user2inGroup@xxx.com,.....**

this is part of my code, i tried deleting the "to" field, but nothing seems to work.

```
void ownRoutingAgent_OnResolvedMessage(ResolvedMessageEventSource source, QueuedMessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
      {
          bool forwardToSeg = false;

          if (true) EventViewerLogger.WriteInfo("FromAddress: " + messageEventArgs.MailItem.FromAddress.ToString());
          if (true) EventViewerLogger.WriteInfo("SecureSenders: " + m_SecureSenderAddress);

          distGroupList = generateDistGroupList();


                  ////////////////////////////////////////////
                  //Check if recepient is a distrebution group

                  Random rnd = new Random();
                  int numOfUser = rnd.Next(0, senderAddresses.Length);
                  messageEventArgs.MailItem.FromAddress = new RoutingAddress(senderAddresses[numOfUser]);

                  // run over all recipients list
                  //foreach (EnvelopeRecipient recp in messageEventArgs.MailItem.Recipients)
                  //{
                  foreach (MyClass disGrp in distGroupList)
                  {
                      // Checks if Recipients contain an e-mail group.
                      // if yes, does not route to seg.
                      if (messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.To[0].NativeAddress.ToString().ToUpper() == disGrp.emailAdress.ToUpper())

                      {
                          messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.To[0].NativeAddress.Remove(0);
                          messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.To.Remove(new EmailRecipient(messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.To[0].DisplayName.ToString(),messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.To[0].NativeAddress.ToString()));

                          foreach (EnvelopeRecipient yywx in messageEventArgs.MailItem.Recipients)
                          {
                              //remove group address from mail-recipients


                              //   messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.To.Add*******
                              //       = messageEventArgs.MailItem.Recipients


                              //add all group members to the "TO" field


                              //messageEventArgs.MailItem.Recipients;

                          }
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the AddressBook class to do that or expand the recipients of a message in a Transport Agent . if you want to expand a list that would requires an AD call which can be very costly in terms of performance in a Transport Agent.